# Use win32 libs in cmake project

Tags: c++, winapi, cmake, winhttp

I'm trying to build a cmake project that uses WinHTTP. Below is my cmakelists.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(Mandarin_EXE_Updator)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

set(WIN32 True)

OPTION(WINHTTP ON)

add_executable(Mandarin_Updator WIN32 ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(winhttp)
```

I've tried doing `link_libraries` and `target_link_libraries` but with no luck. I think i need to use `link_libraries`, but with the full path to the lib file.

below is the output of `cmake --build .`

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.8.3+39993bd9d for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSVCRTD.lib(exe_winmain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol WinMain referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)
" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ) [C:\Users\srika\OneDrive\Desktop\Mandarin.EXE\Mandarin Updater\build\Mandarin_Updator.vcxproj]
C:\Users\srika\OneDrive\Desktop\Mandarin.EXE\Mandarin Updater\build\Debug\Mandarin_Updator.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved ext
ernals [C:\Users\srika\OneDrive\Desktop\Mandarin.EXE\Mandarin Updater\build\Mandarin_Updator.vcxproj]
```

Comment: you need to specify the target for `target_link_libraries`, also try `winhttp.lib`

Comment: @AlanBirtles I've just tried that and i still get the same error

Comment: and what error is that?

Comment: I've edited the original post to contain my build error

Comment: presumably you haven't defined a `WinMain` function or if you meant to create a console application remove `WIN32` from `add_executable`